# perl's text::template module ... what is the closest match for php?

Tags: php, html, perl, templates

I love the [Text::Template](http://p3rl.org/Text%3a%3aTemplate) module for Perl and HTML.  It allows me to keep my HTML separate from my logic and I can use Dreamweaver to continually maintain the HTML design.

Don't be mislead by the name Text::Template, it is not like [Smarty](http://www.smarty.net/). Text::Template is a more elegant and simpler solution than the Smarty philosophy.

I think the [TinyButStrong template engine](http://www.tinybutstrong.com/) may be the answer to my own question, but I welcome your feedback.

Comment: I just found this site which my be a good answer to my question?
http://www.tinybutstrong.com/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[tinybutstrong](http://www.tinybutstrong.com/)

Answer (score 1):

The most complete implementation of that in PHP is probably [Smarty](http://www.smarty.net/).

Though, in my opinion way overkill.

PHP itself is a template language, meaning you can embed PHP directly into HTML files, you might interested in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62617/whats-the-best-way-to-separate-php-code-and-html

Comment: My google searching has shown that smarty is the most popular templating solution for php, BUT it does not operate like text::template.  I'm still reading the tinybutstrong docs, but I think it may be a much closer match for text::template.

Comment: I'm not very versed in Perl, but Smarty seems to have all of the functionality of it and then some...what about it doesn't operate similarly?

Comment: Smarty seems like overkill and lacks elegant simplicity.. checkout the tinybutstrong examples page... it seems much closer to text::template
http://www.tinybutstrong.com/examples.php
Does smarty handle full separation (1 html file and 1 php file)?